# Tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Trying to build my own custom dataset all easy sailing till I get to tf_records when I try and run the following code:

```
python3 generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/train_labels.csv  --output_path=data/train.record
```

to build the tr_records for my custom object detection I am getting the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 101, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 92, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 47, in create_tf_example
    encoded_jpg = fid.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 115, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 75, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/david/models/research/object_detection/images/000000004765.jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert but I think that

```
--csv_input=data/train_labels.csv
```

should actually be:

```
--csv_input="C:/admin/directories_in_between/data/train_labels.csv"
```

or something along those lines if the file you are trying to find is located on your computer.

Try changing it for both and see if works.

Comment: Using a Linux Machine.